# how to protect controller actions in MVC 2 DotNetOpenAuth multiple providers scenario

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to develop an MVC site that implements dotnotopenauth. I have a user table, provider table and a user to provider table. I am storing the returned auth string.

I am using forms auth cookies for user authentication. I am wonder, and this could be a very simple question for someone... how to protect certain controller actions for authenticated users only.. Is it as simple as isAuthenticated? Is their some action decorator or something. I am just starting with this so thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to decorate your controllers with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

Comment: so does this work specifically with formsauthorization cookie?

Comment: It works with whatever authentication mechanism you've wired into ASP.NET's web.config file.  Yes, FormsAuthentication cookies work fine here, as do others.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article on the topic.  It is not straight-forward since [Authorize] applies to Membership Provider code and DotNetOpenAuth applies to OAuth technology, that is external to Membership.

The basic idea is that the two need to be merged first, as explained by ...

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/899303.aspx